# Converting numbers with letters into negatives SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm importing flat files into a sql database. Said flat files are generated by an older piece of software that can't store negative numbers and thus uses letters instead. p=0, q=1, r=2, etc. and then since you found/replaced a letter you multiply by -1. So if I get 14q, that needs to be converted into -141. I feel like the type conversions will be the trickiest part of this, as I'd need to import them as strings but then multiply by -1 once I replace the letter.

Whatever number you replace with, you multiply by -1.

- 14p=-140
- 14q=-141
- 14r=-142
- 140=140

The extracts are wide, easily 80+ column(s) of "numeric" data to account for so re-usable approach would be a bonus

Comment: Typo?  How does 14q become +141.1 ?   Why not -14?

Comment: Why is `14q` -141` if q is `-1`? I'd expect, *maybe* `q41`. Do you have to take the letter at the end, map it to the negative, and then move it to the front?

Comment: The pattern is you need to convert the character to a number then multiply that by the value, yes? What does p = -0 mean? Literally multiply by zero or is that an indicator it's not actually negative?

Comment: fixed width file with 3 characters and the need to have numbers anywhere between 999 through -999. No typo. Q represents that you should replace it with a 1 and then multiply the number by -1. So 14q, replace the q = 141, multiply by -1 = -141.

I make no comment defending how the original developer made this software, but this is how they decided to do it.

Comment: @billinkc whatever number you replace with, you multiply by -1. 14p=-140, 14q=-141, 14r=-142, etc.

Comment: oh, now i get it, your example wasn't great because it was 1...1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have 80 columns to apply this too. I would seriously consider a script component with your translation done in a method.

```
    private static int ConvertToInt(string val)
    {
        //split to translate then recombine
        string firstPart = val.Substring(0, val.Length - 1);
        string secondPart = val.Substring(val.Length - 1);

        switch (secondPart.ToLower())
        {
            case "p":
                return int.Parse(string.Concat("-", firstPart, "0"));
            case "q":
                return int.Parse(string.Concat("-", firstPart, "1"));
            case "r":
                return int.Parse(string.Concat("-", firstPart, "2"));
            case "s":
                return int.Parse(string.Concat("-", firstPart, "3"));
            case "t":
                return int.Parse(string.Concat("-", firstPart, "4"));
            case "u":
                return int.Parse(string.Concat("-", firstPart, "5"));
            case "v":
                return int.Parse(string.Concat("-", firstPart, "6"));
            case "w":
                return int.Parse(string.Concat("-", firstPart, "7"));
            case "x":
                return int.Parse(string.Concat("-", firstPart, "8"));
            case "y":
                return int.Parse(string.Concat("-", firstPart, "9"));
            default:
                return int.Parse(string.Concat(firstPart, secondPart));
        }

    }

//Simply call the method like this inside the standard row processing section.
int newColumn.Value = ConvertToInt(Row.ColumnName.Value);
```

Note: I added a ToLower() because I see you are mixing case. C# is strict case sensitive.

Comment: Would this be doable in SSIS/derived column transformation or would I need to update in sql after the import? If the latter then I think I'd need to make a staging table with the field as a string and then update the main table with values while converting using translate. If it is doable in derived, what would the expression be?

Comment: a script component is similar to a derived column except you manage column conversion using code. This will be implemented prior to loading to the database.

Comment: It worked fine for my small scale test, but moving it to big scale suddenly the inputbuffer doesn't have definitions of variables. Probably something stupid on my part but I'd appreciate the input https://imgur.com/a/maIYlPG

Comment: Figured it out. It automatically took the underscores out of the variable names. So in order to reference MAEINW_SP_POS_EIN_1_1 I had to write row.MAEINWSPPOSEIN11

Comment: @babno Glad this worked out. I just typed all that into the answer box without testing! The SSIS way to do this is to add all the new columns to output and mark the incoming columns as readonly in the GUI. If this was all a console app, then you could of done all this with looping instead of typing out all the columns. The better you get at c#, the more likely you will move all of your imports into C# Console apps especially anything with XML or JSON (apis) or anything that is kind of complicated like this. Happy programming...

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a "fun" problem. Having worked on many ... creative space saving solutions from old programs, I feel ya.

It sounds like the pattern might be DIGITS with an optional suffix.

Bring that column into the data flow as a string.

Use a Derived Column to create a new column called `Suffix`

```
right(myColumn,1)
```

Now we have the column in the data flow, it might be a digit or it might be a character so we have to inspect it and make a determination. Given the limited range of values, I'd use a lookup component and use the following query

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
(
    VALUES
        (N'p', '0', -1)
    ,   (N'q', '1', -1)
    ,   (N'r', '2', -1)
    ,   (N's', '3', -1)
    ,   (N't', '4', -1)
    ,   (N'u', '5', -1)
    ,   (N'v', '6', -1)
    ,   (N'w', '7', -1)
    ,   (N'x', '8', -1)
    ,   (N'y', '9', -1)
    ,   (N'0', '0', 1)
    ,   (N'1', '1', 1)
    ,   (N'2', '2', 1)
    ,   (N'3', '3', 1)
    ,   (N'4', '4', 1)
    ,   (N'5', '5', 1)
    ,   (N'6', '6', 1)
    ,   (N'7', '7', 1)
    ,   (N'8', '8', 1)
    ,   (N'9', '9', 1)
)D(Suffix, Digit, Multiplier);
```

We will match the Suffix from the Data Flow to lkp_Suffix in our Lookup, bringing back the lkp_Digit and lkp_Multiplier values.

Add another Derived Column, this will build out our new "number" with string manipulation. Let's call this `myIntermediateColumn`

```
left(myColumn, len(myColumn) -1) + lkp_Digit
```

Add a third Derived Column. This will convert our intermediate column to a number and perform the math to make it negative (or not). Call it `myActualNumber`

```
(DT_I4) myIntermediateColumn * lkp_Digit
```

If everything has lined up, we took the final character off our original column. Used a lookup to translate that 1 value to 2: the digit it represents along with a value we'll use to flip the sign accordingly. We created a new column that replaces the final character with our looked up value. Finally, we create another column that converts our data type back to a number and does the math to set the sign appropriately. Land that column into your table

NULLs or empty strings in your data set will mess you up but the nice thing about the multi-derived column approach is you can set a ... data inspector between them to identify where a task when wrong. You could do this in fewer steps at the cost of maintainability.

Comment: Sounds promising. Though one correction, it's not "that column", it's "those 80 columns"... Will report back.... eventually...

Comment: You gave me another idea that I think might be easier, if SSIS is capable of it. Would appreciate your 2c.

The first 2 characters are always numbers. What if I brought the first 2 in as a number, and the last as a character. Then I would use derived column to replace the first one, multiply by 10, (do I need another derived column here?) have a case statement to add an amount according to the values list (need a 3rd derived here?), and then if it was a letter multiple by -1.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you could use `TRANSLATE` to change the last "digit" (letter) to the correct digit and then multiply the value by `-1` or `1` depending on if the letters p-y appeared in the string:

```sql
SELECT V.YourNotInt,
       TRY_CONVERT(int,TRANSLATE(V.YourNotInt,'pqrstuvwxy','0123456789')) * CASE WHEN V.YourNotInt LIKE '%[p-y]' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END AS YourInt
FROM (VALUES('14p'),
            ('4q'),
            ('52'),
            ('35r'))V(YourNotInt);
```

Comment: Would this be doable in SSIS/derived column transformation or would I need to update in sql after the import? If the latter then I think I'd need to make a staging table with the field as a string and then update the main table with values while converting using translate.

If it is doable in derived, what would the expression be? I made some quick dummy files and test table and tried
>TRY_CONVERT(int,TRANSLATE(mytestint,'pqrstuvwxy','0123456789')) * CASE WHEN mytestint LIKE '%[p-y]' THEN -1 ELSE 1
but it didn't like that

Comment: Do you mean a computed column, @babno ? The expression would be identical. Expressions for columns don't different because they are in a `SELECT` or not.

Comment: I'm in the data flow and only see derived column as a likely candidate. Googling for computed column returns results for derived column so not sure if you're referring to something different.

I tried in a select as well but it still didn't like it. I believe you're not allowed to use case statements in expressions.

Comment: Ahh, I see, yeah, I'd probably go with staging the data in the database by inserting the "raw" data, and then transforming from staging to production, @babno .